# Easily interchange objects in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` of `UIViews` that I put in `UIScrollView` which is responsible for putting them in order. Right now I have this code for changing two `UIViews` positions with each other:

```
UIView *viewToBeChanged = [views objectAtIndex:self.page];
UIView *previousView = [views objectAtIndex:previousPage];

[views removeObjectAtIndex:self.page];
[views removeObjectAtIndex:previousPage];

[views insertObject:viewToBeChanged atIndex:previousPage];
[views insertObject:previousView atIndex:self.page];
```

Is there a better way to change the position of an object in `NSMutableArray` with another one? Thanks!

Comment: Use this [exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BCIJIGDB)

Comment: You can use `replaceObjectAtIndex: withObject:` or `exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:` or `replaceObjectAtIndex: withObjectAtIndex:`as per your requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [replaceObjectAtIndex:i](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/replaceObjectAtIndex%3awithObject%3a) method

```
 [array replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:newObj];
```

You can also use [exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/exchangeObjectAtIndex%3awithObjectAtIndex%3a):

```
  [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:j];
```